# Error in readJPEG(location) : unable to open D:\kuliah\semester8\dataset

Tags: r

```
library(jpeg)
location <- "D:\\kuliah\\semester8\\dataset"
img <- readJPEG(location)
```

> Error in readJPEG(location) : unable to open D:\kuliah\semester8\dataset

Comment: What is D:\kuliah\semester8\dataset? Is it a JPEG file without an extension? If it's a directory then I don't imagine you can just readJPEG it.

Comment: `?readJPEG`: "source - either name of the file to read from or a raw vector representing the JPEG file content".